# Creating custom buttons for UIBarButton, selector throwing exception

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am creating a custom button with its own image, and assigning it to the rightbarbutton of a nabvigationcontroller I have. The problem is that when the user clicks on the button I get an exceptoin about my controller not recognizing that selctor??

```
UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image1.size.width/1.8, image1.size.height/1.8);
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:imgRect];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextScreenButtonAction)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


UIBarButtonItem *barButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myButton];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false;
```

Comment: may be this the problem `nextScreenButtonAction` change it to `[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextScreenButtonAction:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`

Comment: That did it, wow, now please explain why the : added at the end did the difference?

Comment: In your method definition you be passing and argument like `-(IBAction) nextScreenButtonAction:(id)sender{}` so in the addTarget you need to specify a colon(:) to indicate parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is the problem `nextScreenButtonAction` change it to

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextScreenButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

In your method definition you be passing and argument like

```
-(IBAction) nextScreenButtonAction:(id)sender
{
}
```

so in the addTarget you need to specify a colon(:) to indicate parameter

Answer (score 0):

In response to below code,

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextScreenButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Make sure that you have create method in the same class like,

```
- (void) nextScreenButtonAction
{
   // write your logic here...
}
```